# Firestore update value in map of maps

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to add values to a map of maps using cloud functions and firestore. The maps might not exist and there can not be an entry with the `personID` key.

Right now I am accomplishing this by the following code:

```
if (!userData!.requests){
    userData["requests"] = {};
}
if (!userData!.requests.outgoing){
    userData!.requests["outgoing"] = {};
}

userData!.requests.outgoing[`${personID}`] = data;
t.update(usersRef, userData!);
```

Is there an easier way to do this? And is there a way without the need to read the data first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have maps, you should be able to [use dot notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) to write/update a nested field:

```
usersRef.update({
    ["requests.outgoing."+personID]: data
})
```

If you have an array anywhere in the path to the data, this won't work though. You can only [add/remove items in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) without reading them, updating any existing array element requires a read-update-write cycle.

Comment: I had to add squared brackets to make it work: `["requests.outgoing."+personID]: data` .

Comment: Ooops.... good catch. I already thought the code look odd when I posted it, but couldn't immediately see. Thanks for catching the mistake and letting me know!