# How to add or edit specific value within a map on a firestore document?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a a map within a firestore document that looks like this:

[image]

Right now I am confused on how to:

1. Update the value of the one item in the map
2. Add a new value to the map

I thought Update() would be my best option based on the documentation:

Set() in firestore:

> To create or overwrite a single document, use the set() method:

Update() in firestore:

> To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the update() method:

So I want to update just my inPack map. I am doing that with this code:

```
                    db
                        .collection('GearLockerItems')
                        .doc(doc.reference.id)
                        .update(
                      {
                        'inPack': {packID: false},
                      },
                    );
```

My issue is that it is overwriting the valueId and not adding a new valueID. So I am updating the inPack by overwriting the entire thing. I think I am not getting down to the next level and am stuck.

Comment: By valueId, do you mean packID ?

Comment: So I think I just solved it with the dot notation referenced in this stackoverflow :-)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70199203/firestore-update-value-in-map-of-maps

Comment: so I changed my code to this:

                            db
                                .collection('GearLockerItems')
                                .doc(doc.reference.id)
                                .update(
                              {
                                'inPack.$packID': false,
                              },
                            );

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. You can see my answer as well showing what you also discovered :)

Comment: perfect! I cant accept it yet its to quick lol. But I will accept it in a few minutes. Thanks for all the help today!

Comment: Great! No worries, do it when you get the time. It was clear questions, easier to help then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dot notation as follows:

```
db
    .collection('GearLockerItems')
    .doc(doc.reference.id)
    .update({'inPack.$packId': false},
);
```

From the official documentation:

> Dot notation allows you to update a single nested field without
> overwriting other nested field. If you update a nested field without
> dot notation, you will overwrite the entire map field